# Is it possible to add properties to a serialized collection?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, collections, xml-serialization

Is there a way to add elements and attributes to a serialized collection subclass?

Here's an example, given the following class:

```
[XmlRoot("MyTs")]
public class MyCollection : HashSet<MyT>
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //[XmlElement]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The serialized XML does no contain the additional element and attribute. Is there a way to add it, which still using the serialization class as `HashSet` subclass?

For the above example, I want the following XML:

```
<?xml>
<MyTs name="name">
  <MyT/>
  <MyT/>
  <MyT/>
  <Description>Some long verbal rubbish</Description>
</MyTs>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To `XmlSerializer`, something is *either* a collection *xor* a data object. Not both.

You can, however, do:

```
[XmlRoot("MyTs")]
public class MyRoot
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //[XmlElement]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    private readonly HashSet<MyT> items = new HashSet<MyT>();
    [XmlElement("MyT")] 
    public HashSet<MyT> Items {get { return items;}}
}
```

which will have the xml structure you want.

Comment: I guess that *xor* is a typo, you mean *or* isn't it?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel it was intentional; I was disambiguating the casual conversational use of "or" (where it tends to be exclusive) from the programming/mathematical use of "or" (where it is inclusive). This "or" is meant in the exclusive sense: aka "xor"